# class template SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, sfinae

I'm testing class template SFINAE.

```
template<typename T, typename...Types>
using enable_if_class = T;

template<typename T, typename...Types>
struct enable_if_test;

template<typename T>
struct enable_if_test<T, enable_if_class<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_const<T>::value, int>::type>> {
    enable_if_test() {
        std::cout << "const version!\n";
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct enable_if_test<T, enable_if_class<T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_const<T>::value, int>::type>> {
    enable_if_test() {
        std::cout << "nonconst version!\n";
    }
};
```

the above codes get compiled on g++, but get error on clang++ and visual studio. when codes change to:

```
template<typename T, typename...Types>
using enable_if_class = T;

template<typename T, typename...Types>
struct enable_if_test;

template<typename T>
struct enable_if_test<T, enable_if_class<void, typename std::enable_if<std::is_const<T>::value, int>::type>> {
    enable_if_test() {
        std::cout << "const version!\n";
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct enable_if_test<T, enable_if_class<void, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_const<T>::value, int>::type>> {
    enable_if_test() {
        std::cout << "nonconst version!\n";
    }
};
```

this time only g++ gets error.
so here is my question, is this a compiler bug or my code is illegal?
if this is a compiler bug, is there some reason cause this bug?

Comment: please include the error messages in the question

Comment: BTW, here g++ accepts both versions [Demo (`T`)](https://godbolt.org/z/d4Cw8D), [Demo (`void`)](https://godbolt.org/z/CPwARH).

Answer (score 0):

In GCC, this is a compiler bug visible in version 4.9.4 and lower, and fixed in version 5.1.

[GCC 4.9.4 Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsQAZlKtmtUMgCkAJgBCM2aQDOmdsgJ46lTLXQBhVKwCuAW1pdhO9ABk8tTADlTAI0zEQ04QAdUSwptoDYzMLUh8/DTpbeycTV3dPZVVMdQCGAmZiAiDTc05hFTVI2nTMgmjHFzcPAoysnJD85Tryu0q46s8ASmVUI2JkDgByGUE7ZGMsAGpJQT1NJQJiTGYTWexJAAYAQS3tgkwTL1ED2b0CAE8vHVXMKYAVUinL69pbgDpP%2B6vMJXW9ox%2BcRTG7OdgAfTwVHBE2YSiUM0EABEHrN5Ds9gcjidMGcXjcTHdHs8fm9CZ93t9rn9BBsdotiEZ1CC3mDMJDoQdFmi9pjDsdmKc5viyUT/vSlkyCCzmGyOeCuQQzsTQRCoTDRPCzgA3VB4dBPEW3KaLdAgECq9lQs6m814JQwujcub3dbm7VsIyYJ52JW0834/60mYAdnR2ymkZlcvViogXVD4ajyZNBDNKD60rOZxm0mkaFoiym2rcfjoYDAkgArHpaDJpDydsnJCGkbzW43djssQKhedScbXbS9gypdG1Zzfn69CrWRONXCaXpdfrDQPCan05aOWcK7aQPbHYXp0PsO7Pd6pr63SBA8Pgy2k1Ht7Gp/HE3sU1H92gjFm5jm9a0HQBZFiWxBlrQFbVrW9ads2HYYh2gjhnsvpTCYzB2O%2Bj7tkiQw9KwIBDFWQykOYQybGRqDEXoCgKCafQDHcoyCGRBDEVRXQ9AgKxYO48akAA1iAVabCIxHcGRFFUaQNFDGRSggOJHGUQRpBwLAMCIBmRx4OwZAUBAaB6QZIDANwACcvBUPpBwQZQzicWRzh2JkFzEZwZEmYS9AAPK0KwHlqaQWCYeI7DOaFeDLKkJZKSFmAAB4pH%2Bwyyb6qhRaweDOMQ7kGFgnnscQeAmMVPQ0PQTBsBwPD8FwIhiBI9FyCIuVKZAPSoF4xQJQAtKasxIlIcgKJwXlJEUATaLoDR5KQVgVLE8SNeE/h0PNa2%2BBttDLVU7icFNKTFKU9SGLkjWFCdaQtPtHSHc0ZRbUdixlPdq2cD0ShMYMQiEcRpHkVF8lJQAHAAbP1EPcFMwDIMgUzcO8lnvLDEC4IQJC5oIwhTAYpluDjX3461sjsc53HCUIgjvLj9MM4zElDFJpDlWJwMhfJinKaQqlcRp2kQEgmZeH%2B5CUCZXj6dUR2YPgRDuMIVWMCwkX1QA7vlXgVczQMydRxGjJwUwa4QCBTODUMw3DCNIyjaMU2pVO8cw/GUADLNkez4kG3JxE8yplM9CJHNEUMbGc7J3N88HzPSNJIMB7Hzs9OBkEgNwQA%3D%3D%3D)

[GCC 5.1 Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsQAZlKtmtUMgCkAJgBCM2aQDOmdsgJ46lTLXQBhVKwCuAW1pdhO9ABk8tTADlTAI0zEQ04QAdUSwptoDYzMLUh8/DTpbeycTV3dPZVVMdQCGAmZiAiDTc05hFTVI2nTMgmjHFzcPAoysnJD85Tryu0q46s8ASmVUI2JkDgByGUE7ZGMsAGpJQT1NJQJiTGYTWexJAAYAQS3tgkwTL1ED2b0CAE8vHVXMKYAVUinL69pbgDpP%2B6vMJXW9ox%2BcRTG7OdgAfTwVHBE2YSiUM0EABEHrN5Ds9gcjidMGcXjcTHdHs8fm9CZ93t9rn9BBsdotiEZ1CC3mDMJDoQdFmi9pjDsdmKc5viyUT/vSlkyCCzmGyOeCuQQzsTQRCoTDRPCzgA3VB4dBPEW3KaLdAgECq9lQs6m814JQwujcub3dbm7VsIyYJ52JW0834/60mYAdnR2ymkZlcvViogXVD4ajyZNBDNKD60rOZxm0mkaFoiym2rcfjoYDAkgArHpaDJpDydsnJCGkbzW43djssQKhedScbXbS9gypdG1Zzfn69CrWRONXCaXpdfrDQPCan05aOWcK7aQPbHYXp0PsO7Pd6pr63SBA8Pgy2k1Ht7Gp/HE3sU1H92gjFm5jm9a0HQBZFiWxBlrQFbVrW9ads2HYYh2gjhnsvpTCYzB2O%2Bj7tkiQw9KwIBDFWQykOYQybGRqDEXoCgKCafQDHcoyCGRBDEVRXQ9AgKxYO48akAA1iAVabCIxHcGRFFUaQNFDGRSggOJHGUQRpBwLAMCIBmRx4OwZAUBAaB6QZIDAFWnDiVQ%2BkHBBlDOJxZHOHYmQXMRnBkSZhL0AA8rQrDuWppBYJh4jsE5IV4MsqQlkpwWYAAHikf7DLJvqqJFrB4M4xBuQYWAeexxB4CYRU9DQ9BMGwHA8PwXAiGIEj0XIIg5UpkA9KgXjFPFAC0pqzEiUhyAonCeUkRQBNougNHkpBWBUsTxA14T%2BHQc2rb4620EtVTuJwk0pMUpT1IYuQNYUx1pC0e0dAdzRlJth2LGUd0rZwPRKExgxCIRxGkeRkXyYlAAcABsfXg9wUzAMgyBTFW7ycFMEC4IQJC5oIwhTAYpluFjn24y1sjsU53HCUIgjvNjtN0/TElDFJpBlWJQPBfJinKaQqlcRp2kQEgmZeH%2B5CUCZXj6dUh2YPgRDuMIlWMCwEV1QA7nlXjlYzgMydRxGjCjauEAgUxg5D0Ow/DiPI2TakU7xzD8ZQ/1M2RrPiXrcnEVzKnkz0Ils0RQxsezsmczz/uM9I0nAz7kf2z04GQSA3BAA%3D)

I would suggest you to use newer version of either GCC or CLANG.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bug of clang/msvc similar to the  CWG ([1558](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1558)) spotted by [`std::void_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t), as using:

```
template<typename T, typename...Types>
struct enable_if_class_impl
{
    using type = T;
};

template<typename T, typename...Types>
using enable_if_class = typename enable_if_class_impl<T, Types...>::type;
```

makes all compilers happy:

[Demo (`T`)](https://godbolt.org/z/zUDGat)

[Demo (`void`)](https://godbolt.org/z/2n-Uq_)